# How to set electron appId on development mode

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

Im using framework that needs specfic appId postfix in appId and reject futher loading if app doesnt contain it. So far in production app built and works as expected but in dev it is not possible to run. How can I change appId for development stage?